# How to use flutter provider in parent "Products" screen and child "Product" screen

Tags: flutter, firebase, provider

I have the following App in Flutter (please see **attached image**):

1. A **parent screen**, showing a **list of products**, as queried from **Firestore collection**, using Stream Subscription (so that if the data changes, it's reflected in that screen)
2. A **child screen**, showing a **selected product** (data from a **Firestore document**). If the data in this document changes (price change for example), this screen should show the updated data

[image]

I can achieve this using Stream subscription to the products collection for the parent screen, and stream subscription to the product document for the child screen.
But I guess that I can utilize provider for this, and use a smarter way of doing so (updates to the data in the parent screen reflected in the child screen)...

As someone new to **Provider**, I'd love to hear (see a code snippet) how to do that?

**EDIT:**
I know I can use stream provider to get the "products" part.
I guess my question is: after I get updated with the products list in the parent screen (using StreamProvider), how do I store the selected product data in the parent screen, so that is available (and notify on changes) in the child screen?

Comment: Have you considered [StreamProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider-class.html)?

Comment: I guess my question is: after I get updated with the products list in the parent screen (using StreamProvider), how do I store the selected product data in the parent screen, so that is available (and notify on changes) in the child screen?